# Inconsistency of genetic matching using MatchIt package

Tags: r

Every time when I run matchit function (method = "genetic"), the results are  different. The code, of course, is identical. What do you think could be the reason for it?

Comment: If you want the results to be replicable, set the seed before running your code using `set.seed()`.

Comment: Thank very much, Noah

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that it uses stochastic algorithm (please see http://sekhon.berkeley.edu/papers/MatchingJSS.pdf)